# Disable client validation on request asp.net core 2.1 razor pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core 2.1 App I have a form with multiple buttons, input text box and a Dropdown list.

One of the button add a record which name is taken either from input text box or the list. Other buttons do some other job.

I use this typical construction to run the validation:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The problem is that if the item is selected in the dropdown list but text box stays empty I cannot submit the form due to validation error as the variable for check box is declared as

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Book's name is required")]
```

Other buttons also generate post and the same happens: form cannot be submitted if the text box is empty :-/

Is there any way to exclude elements on client side from being checked on condition?.. I assume, I probably need a JavaScript here, but I'm quite new in this stuff :-/

Would appreciate any help on that.